# QGIS Plugin: Running progress bar within basic plugin which was created in Qt designer, how to run proportional to processing steps and close dialog

Tags: qgis-plugins, qt-designer

I am trying to run my plugin with a progress bar. The progress bar I have added was created in Qt designer (name: progressBar) and currently just runs independently to my processing steps:

```
from PyQt5 import uic
# PyQGIS: e.g. QgsVectorLaye
from qgis.core import *

import processing

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

import os
import time
import logging
import sys

pluginPath=os.path.dirname(__file__)
uiPath=os.path.join(pluginPath, 'CD.ui')


WIDGET, BASE = uic.loadUiType(uiPath)

class GUF(BASE, WIDGET):

    def __init__(self, iface):
        super().__init__(iface.mainWindow())
        self.setupUi(self)
      
        

        self.btn_inputFile1.clicked.connect(self.getPathFile1)
        self.btn_inputFile2.clicked.connect(self.getPathFile2)
        self.btn_inputFile3.clicked.connect(self.getPathFile3)
        self.btn_inputFile4.clicked.connect(self.getPathFile4)
        
        self.btn_output.clicked.connect(self.getOutputFile)
        self.btn_run.clicked.connect(self.runGeoprocessing)

        self.btn_cancel.clicked.connect(self.close)
        
    def printProgress(value: int):
        print('progress: {} %'.format(value))
    
    def getPathFile1(self):
        datei = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Select layer 1', filter="*.tif") 
        
        self.txt_inputFile1.setText(datei[0])
        
    def getPathFile2(self):
        datei = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Select layer 2', filter="*.shp") 
        
        self.txt_inputFile2.setText(datei[0])
        
    def getPathFile3(self):
        datei = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Select layer 3', filter="*.shp")
        
        self.txt_inputFile3.setText(datei[0])
        
    def getPathFile4(self):
        datei = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Select layer 4', filter="*.shp") 
        
        self.txt_inputFile4.setText(datei[0])
        
    def getOutputFile(self):
        file = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, 'Select output name and directory', filter="*.shp")  
        self.txt_output.setText(file[0]) 
        
    def runGeoprocessing(self):
        self.progressBar.reset()
        for i in range(101):
            self.progressBar.setValue(i)
            # do something useful here instead of sleep
            time.sleep(0.5)

        # clip
        resultsclip = processing.run("gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer", {'INPUT':self.txt_inputFile1.text(),'MASK':self.txt_inputFile4.text(),'SOURCE_CRS':None,'TARGET_CRS':None,'NODATA':1,'ALPHA_BAND':False,'CROP_TO_CUTLINE':True,'KEEP_RESOLUTION':False,'SET_RESOLUTION':False,'X_RESOLUTION':None,'Y_RESOLUTION':None,'MULTITHREADING':False,'OPTIONS':'','DATA_TYPE':0,'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
 
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Clip completed', 'Engine', Qgis.Success)
        
        
        # reclassify
        resultsreclassify = processing.run("native:reclassifybytable", {'INPUT_RASTER':resultsclip['OUTPUT'],'RASTER_BAND':1,'TABLE':[-2,0,1,1,2,1],'NO_DATA':-9999,'RANGE_BOUNDARIES':0,'NODATA_FOR_MISSING':False,'DATA_TYPE':5,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Reclassify completed', 'Engine', Qgis.Success)
```

How do I make the progress bar run with each step of my processing, so that it is proportional? How does the dialog automatically close when processing is completed?